# Do I need to manually refresh banner ads using Facebook Audience network?

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-audience-network

This is my first time using Audience Network and I do not have this clear.
I can successfully show a banner ad but I am not sure if I need to refresh it every X time or it refreshes it self.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For every activity our code starts from `onCreate` method, as our `loadad()` is within `onCreate()`, there is no need to refresh it manually.

```
private AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ...
  // Instantiate an AdView object. 

  adView = new AdView(this, "#YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);

  // Find the Ad Container
  LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_container);

  // Add the ad view to your activity layout
  adContainer.addView(adView);

  // Request an ad
  adView.loadAd();
}`
```

Comment: I am using same activity, so should I refresh the ad every time?

Answer (score 0):

No need to refresh the ad, but you may need to release the resources used by adView using the following code to your activity's onDestroy().

Hope this helps you to utilze the resources well.

```
protected void onDestroy()
{
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```